# Issue with remapping keys using autohotkey in games

Tags: autohotkey

I used autohotkey to remap a key that wasnt functioning to another key. it works alright but at some certain areas. it doesn't work fully well with some games. tried a lot of modifications but still the same result. then again im a newbie in using autohotkey so any insights on what i could do to fix it.

Comment: You're asking in the wrong location. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question may be better off at superuser.com, Stack Overflow is about programming.

Comment: See [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#games).

Comment: Your game likely takes direct input from the keyboard. In that case remapping normally with AHK will have no effect. To get past this, you'd want to remap keys on hardware driver level. See [AHI](https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception) for example.